# Device changes alphabet of strings

Tags: android

My application is in Serbian. In Serbia we use two alphabets (keyboards): Latin and Cyrillic. They have the same letters, but are written differently. All of string resources are in the default `string.xml` file, and they are in CYRILLIC keyboard. Tested on an emulator - there are no issues. But the problem appears on a real device:

It renders text in LATIN keyboard. Everything is correct, just in wrong alphabet.

The device uses Serbian Latin as system language. Anybody knows how to prevent this "translation"?

Comment: Which Android version has your device?

Comment: Android 7.0 (Nougat)

Comment: Is [Serbian latin and Serbian Cyrillic in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45717376/2096401) relevant/helpful?

Comment: Thank you, setScript() might be what I need